# Android Listview on top of Keyboardview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-keypad, android-search

Hi I implemented a SearchView which shows results in a ListView.The problem I am facing is that I have a custom keyboard and my Listview is overlapping over the keyboardView so I am not able to press some of the keys on my keyboard.What I want to achieve is my Listview to be displayed under the KeyboardView.Here is my layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/basic_bg" >

<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
    android:id="@+id/keyboardView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />



<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewUp"
    android:background="@drawable/delete_bg_5line"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Destination Input Text"
    android:textColor="#87CEFA" >
</SearchView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/main_list_View"
    android:layout_width="450dp"
    android:layout_height="235dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/searchView"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scrollbars="none" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Also I want to hide the custom keyboard when the user browses through the ListView**
**and code for changing the visibility of keyboard**

```
searchtextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method st4ub
            toggleKeyboardVisibility(searchtextView);

        }

        private void toggleKeyboardVisibility(
                AutoCompleteTextView searchViewWidget) {
            KeyboardView keyboardView = (KeyboardView) findViewById(R.id.keyboardView);
            int visibility = keyboardView.getVisibility();
            switch (visibility) {
            case View.VISIBLE:
                keyboardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case View.GONE:
            case View.INVISIBLE:
                keyboardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                searchtextView = searchViewWidget;
                break;
            }
        }

    });
```

Another thing I want to do is **change the background for my keyboard keys**.I was not able to do this I tried adding android:keyIcon attribute to each of the keys but it did not work and only the preview background image changes when I use this attribute.How do I go about doing this.

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:horizontalGap="0px"
android:keyBackground="@drawable/custom_keyboard_press_onekey"
android:keyWidth="10%p"
android:verticalGap="0px" >

<Row>

    <Key
        android:codes="1"
        android:iconPreview="@drawable/custom_keyboard_press_onekey"
        android:isRepeatable="true"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/custom_keyboard_press_onekey"
        android:keyLabel="1" />
 </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

And this is how I instantiate the keyboard

```
    final KeyboardView keyboardView = (KeyboardView) findViewById(R.id.keyboardView);
    Keyboard keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.layout.keyboard);
    keyboardView.setKeyboard(keyboard);
    keyboardView.setEnabled(true);
    keyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(true);

    keyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
```

Can someone please guide me where I am going wrong or suggest how I should proceed.Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hey If i create a layout in the above way I get the following error "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first". Are you aware of this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view your keyboard above your listview, Change your layout to,

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/basic_bg" >

<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewUp"
    android:background="@drawable/delete_bg_5line"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Destination Input Text"
    android:textColor="#87CEFA" >
</SearchView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/main_list_View"
    android:layout_width="450dp"
    android:layout_height="235dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/searchView"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scrollbars="none" >
</ListView>


<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
    android:id="@+id/keyboardView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```